# User has no attribute session -> Django

Tags: django, authentication, logout

Querying my database to get a user so I can log them out, but getting the above error.

```
def logout(request):
    id = request.session["user_id"]
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=id)
    auth.logout(user)
```

I'm not trying to to say that User has a session attribute, I telling it that it's primary key is equal to the number held in the session.

Comment: why are you defining a `logout()` function instead of just using the `logout()` function from `django.contrib.auth`?

Comment: Two things wrong with this: firstly you don't need a user instance to logout, as Yuji points out: and secondly your user is already in `request.user`, so why query for it again?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`auth.logout()` expects `request` not a user instance. Assuming you're talking about `django.contrib.auth`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.logout

Comment: I am writing a django-admin command so I cannot use "request". Is there any other way to logout user without using request??

Answer (score 0):

To prevent any unwanted recursion avoid naming your view thesame name as the logout function you imported from "django.contrib.auth".

The code should look like:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect("Name of url pattern ")
```